# Shuddering noise from HDD

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I just flipped my laptop open and it made a loud shuddering noise. I freaked out and pulled the SATA out. It sounded like something misaligned rattling while spinning really fast. Windows is installed on `C:\`(SSD, btw).

Right now I'm checking for any bad sector. Halfway through and no bad sectors rn. The shuddering died down after scaring me to death for five minutes. It's reading the data perfectly fine, so I don't think it's a header issue. It wasn't the fan either, the sound didn't come from where the fan was.

I have no idea what the problem is. Assuming it is some sort of HDD fault, how do I back it up without further damage?

(P.S. If it helps, I'm on LG 15U780. HDD is Toshiba MQ04ABF100. I rarely turn my laptop off. I reboot it once a week or so, I usually just close it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Back up the data on the drive while you can still read it**

I cannot stress this enough. If you are worried the drive might be failing, get everything you need off it now. There isn't really a *safe* way to get the data off. You could try plugging it into another computer and copying the data off. That way, you aren't trying to run the OS off the drive as well.

Just because the noise has stopped, it doesn't mean you are safe. You can try looking on google for SMART tools to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Also: try to avoid spinning the drive up/down as much as you can.

Comment: @gronostaj This is a very good point!

Comment: Thanks for your advice. doh what a shame... I'll just back it up and order a new hard drive.

Comment: well the smart tool doesn't give me any fails, so that's good... I'll be buying a new HDD and a dock.

Comment: You are luckier than most. There are a lot of questions from people on here that start with "My hdd was making a noise for 6 months and now it is broken, I need all the data". At least you can still access the data!